# After Sql ALTER table I get - ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, odbc

In Sql Server 2012, after adding two new fields using ALTER, when We try to use the connection again in other queries, We get:

> *ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt*

Note that our connection is done using ODBC Connection.

BTW, when I copy the already altered DB to my DEV machine it also happens.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly didn't close a `DataReader` before building another `DataReader` for the same connection.

Note that the `DataReader` was disposed earlier automatically by the Garbage Collector.
I mentioned that an ALTER TABLE was made adding 2 new fields. The reason the reader wasn't disposed by the GC was because I didn't read all fields out of it (I read all except the 2 new fields).

**The GC collecting the first reader was just luck until I've added those fields.** Afterwards it didn't collect the reader anymore and than I got that exception.

Anyway, I've closed the reader inside a `Finally` block and it works now.

What still remains a mystery is that on Sql Server 2008 and (most surely) on Access I didn't get an exception for the same scenario. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is informing you that you cannot have multiple active queries running on one connection.

To sole it you can :

- Close or Fetch all records from the recordset before doing anything else.
- Open a new connection for the second recordset, while the first
  one is still active.

Comment: I got this at .Fill()
I put in an .Open() & .Close() commands before and after it.
Thx for the hint.

Comment: Correction: I got this at .Fill()
I put in an .Open() & .Close() commands before and after it what is "not necessary" by ref 'cause it opens and closes itself - but looks not always.
Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I would check you are doing a SQLFreeStmt(SQL_CLOSE) or SQLCloseCursor() after your ALTER. For the reason given above by yassine__

Comment: This ALTER is not different than any other ALTER. Also, when I copy the altered DB to my DEV machine it also happens.